# How to add a cc_library / cc_test only for linux

Tags: bazel

My cross-platform project contains some libraries which are only for one platform. How do this with bazel?

I added configurations to use the select function for using different source files. but some libraries and tests should not be build at all.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already started with the select: you can only specify a dependency for select branches for which it exists, bazel itself does that [here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/src/main/cpp/BUILD#L69). Bazel will not build targets that are not dependent upon. Is that enough?

Other solution is to use [compatible_with](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/common-definitions.html#common.compatible_with) or [build tags](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/common-definitions.html#common.tags).

You might find this answer about restricted_to and selects useful: [Use of [bazel] restricted_to attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45381217/use-of-bazel-restricted-to-attribute)